# Finding an element by ID in an AJAX Response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

I need to post data to a php page and then I'd like to get the text of a certain div that is in the response but I can't seem to set things up correctly.  I'm not too good with jQuery but I can usually figure things out fairly quickly... I've been at this for a minute and have tried everything I have found... I think I am just missing the right combination of stuff.

```
$.post("process.php", data , function (response) {  

       var w = window.open();    

       $(w.document.body).html(response); 

       console.log(typeof response); //  yeilds string 
       //create jquery object from the response html
       // var $data = $(response);   // yeilds Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: + whole html text


       var success =  $($.parseHTML(response)).find("#success"); 
       console.log('success'); 
       console.log(success);        // see screenshot
       console.log(success.text()); // yields nothing 
       console.log(success.val());  // yields undefined 
       // if (window.focus) {w.focus()}; 

 },'html');
```

this is the output of `console.log(success);` and the red box is what I want from the response...

![this picture seems really tiny... it wasn't that tiny when I made it.  I hope it is still readable][1]

and this does that:

```
var success =  $(response).find("#success"); 
console.log('success'); 
console.log(success);        // yeilds Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: + whole html text in red
```

Response is...

```
<html><head>
   <style>

      div.totals {
          font-family:calibri; font-size:.9em;  display:inline-block; 
          border-width: 2px;  border-style: solid; border-color: #FFD324; 
          background-color: #FAF5D7; color: #514721; 
          width: 500px; 
          }

      div.error_invalid {
         font-family:calibri; font-size:.9em;  display:inline-block; 
         border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #9999CC; 
         background-color: #EEEEFF; color: #7979B8; 
     }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="totals">Total new rows added: 0 out of 0<br/></div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="totals">Total updated rows: 0 out of 0 <br/></div>

    <div id="success">true</div>
    </body></html>
```

And I have tried removing the style part and I added in the html, head and body tags in hope that it would help....  meaning, I have the same issues if the response only consists of the three divs.

Comment: Can show the `respone`'s content

Comment: yeah.  I wasn't sure if it was needed since what it gave me in the screenshot seemed to be interpreted correctly at that point.

Comment: Have you tried `$(w.document.body).find('#success')`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Notice how all of the elements are on the same *level*? You need to use `.filter()` to narrow down the current selection to a single element in that selection, `.find()` will instead look at the descendants of the current selection.

```
var success =  $($.parseHTML(response)).filter("#success"); 
console.log(success); // div#success
```

Comment: thanks.  can you tell me why... sometimes... (when I googled this problem)... they say to do `$(response)` and other times `$($.parseHTML(response))`

Comment: $.parseHTML is a new method added in 1.8 just for parsing html, It's safer to use $.parseHTML, it does solve a memory leak in some edge cases in IE10, i'm not sure what else it helps with.

Comment: jQuery 1.9 changed how HTML from ajax is handled. Namely, leading whitespace isn't allowed. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md for details.

Comment: In my case `filter` did not worked, only `find` did. I'm using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: @machineaddict it all depends on how the response is structured and where within that structure your target element is.

Comment: How do i print the html of the #success div here?

Comment: `console.log(success.html())`

Answer (score 4):

I got a full 'html' page returned by ajax, but I only need partial of its content, which wrapped by a div and also I need to execute the script inside the 'html' page.

```
 $.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url : "contact.php",
  data: $("#formContactUs").serialize(),
  success: function(msg){
    console.log($(msg)); // this would returned as an array
    console.log(msg);    // return whole html page as string '<html><body>...</body></html>'
    $('#id').html($(content).closest('.target-class'));
    $('#id').append($(content).closest('script')[0]);  // append and execute first script found, when there is more than one script.
  }
});
```

@kevin answer gave hints to why find() is not working as expected, as it only select its descendant but not the first element under consideration. Besides using filter, $.closest() also works if current element is what you are looking for. Well, probably this post quite similar to @Kevin's answer, it's just to suggest another alternative answer and gave more details which hopefully make thing clearer.

Answer (score 2):

try the following if the above answers didn't work

```
var successHtml = $($.parseHTML(response)).find("#success").html();
```

Comment: Thanks bro, really, God bless ya,  i've been 2 days looking for that, lol