# Find Html element in ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery

With AJAX and jQuery 3.3.1 I have this response :

```
var responseText =
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lavender
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lime
    </td>
  </tr>
  <div class="navigation mt-3 text-center" id="ajax-navigation">
    Test
  </div>
```

I want to extract `#ajax-navigation` div.

`$(responseText).find('#ajax-navigation').html()` = *undefined*
`$(responseText).filter('#ajax-navigation').html()` = *undefined*
`$($.parseHTML(responseText)).find('#ajax-navigation').html()` = *undefined*
`$($.parseHTML(responseText)).filter('#ajax-navigation').html()` = *undefined*

Can you help me?
I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240436/finding-an-element-by-id-in-an-ajax-response-with-jquery) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373123/how-to-get-the-specific-div-content-from-responsetext-which-have-complate-html-p)

Comment: The problem is because your HTML snippet is not valid. You cannot have a `div` as a sibling of the `tr`. I'd imagine that the output is completely removing the `div` as a result. I'd suggest fixing whatever code is generating that HTML.

Comment: Oh, thanks. This is AJAX response. I want to add `<tr>` in an existing table and `<div>` after thid table. But I understand, thanks

Comment: yes @Gaylord.P is right. or make response like `var responseText =  '<table><tr>    <td>      Lavender    </td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>      <div class="navigation mt-3 text-center" id="ajax-navigation">    Test  </div>    </td>  </tr> </table> '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```js
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.innerHTML = responseText;
var navigationNode = $("#ajax-navigation", node);
var navigationHTML = navigationNode.html();
```

This should work without changing your responseText